# Latex info help on Ubuntu?

Tags: emacs, ubuntu, documentation

If this is better as an Ubuntu question, I'll direct it there.  Anyway, as a diehard emacs/AucTeX user I'm used to opening up `latex-info` (which uses GNU texinfo) for quick confirmation or reminder on the correct syntax of a command.  However, it doesn't seem to be installed with my current texlive, nor can I find an Ubuntu package which contains it.  I can find latex-info on CTAN, but it doesn't seem to be installed on my system.  I suppose I could install it manually, but that would mean fiddling with info "dir" files.  Is there a package which includes latex-info, or is there another version of latex docs on my system?  (I do have `preview-latex` docs as info files, but not latex itself.)

Comment: Is that the same as `texdoc latex2e` brings up? `texdoc` will find the manual of any package, by the way, so for example `texdoc memoir` will give you `memman.pdf`.

Comment: No, texdoc seems to open up pdf files on my system.  I did end up downloading the latex-info files from CTAN, but they are in fact very old (1992!).  Newer, and possibly better information, is contained at http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ the files of which can be downloaded for local use (such as when you're offline).

Comment: Ah yes, `texdoc` does open up PDFs. Sorry, I should have mentioned that above. I meant to ask if it was the same information, in which case it could be an alternative, even if it is a little less convenient.

Answer (score 2):

The files you're looking for, from [ctan](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex-info), are really old - 1993. So not surprising that they aren't being packaged for Ubuntu. A more recent alternative is [latexrefman](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex-info). This isn't packaged for Ubuntu either, but you can download the .info files for manual installation.

Note that you shouldn't edit the `dir` files by hand - that's what `install-info` is for. I maintain my own personal info directory in `~/.emacs.d/my-info`. Set this up in your .emacs with the following:

```
(add-to-list 'Info-default-directory-list
     "~/.emacs.d/my-info/")
```

You also have to create the directory, of course. The put the info file you want (in this case `latex2e.info`) in that directory, and from the command line call:

```
install-info latex2e.info dir
```

and you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

The package texlive-full should have everything tex related, but texdoc is in texlive-base.
Furthermore, you can search for filenames in packages using apt-file.